# Problem saving file on Motorola Droid, Android 2.1?

Tags: android, motorola-droid

Two of my users have reported a problem with my Android application, OftSeen Gestures. Both of them are using a Motorola Droid. The app saves a text file which is just a list of gesture names and phone numbers, both strings. It saves the file to the private data area. I don't know that it is this code that is failing but they report the assigned numbers disappearing after the phone comes out of screen sleep. Since the file is reread in OnCreate each time, I'm assuming the file doesn't exist on return.

As soon as I can get my hands on a Droid I will debug it but in the meantime can you see a reason why this save operation would fail on Droid (no other users have reported this)?

```
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(AppGlobal.getContext().openFileOutput(MAPPINGS_FILE_NAME, 0));

    for (String key : mMap.keySet()) {
        String number = mMap.get(key).number;
        out.write(String.format("%s,%s\n", key, number == null ? "" : number));
    }
    out.close();
```

AppGlobal.getContext returns the application context and the MAPPINGS_FILE_NAME resolves to "gesture_mappings.txt".

Like I say, I don't know that this is the problem. It could be something else to do with state management inside the app. If anyone has a Droid, maybe they could download the app from Market and test it for me? Note this is a genuine request for help - not an attempt to increase my downloads.

Comment: Seems unlikely but since only Droid (Android 2.1) users have reported this problem, could it be a problem with line-endings?

Comment: Just a detailed report from a Nexus One user with the same issue, so it seems more likely an Android 2.1 problem, although it works okay on the emulator.

Comment: I've received some excellent diagnostics from one of my users. He happens to be French and noticed that if he used accented characters, they caused this problem. So I am wondering if this is to do with character sets.

One entry from the example he gave is this:

HervÃ©,12345678

It seems that when the file is reread, the number is lost. I'm using:

while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
...
String[] kv = str.split(",", 2);
...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was diagnosed as being caused by extended character sets causing line-breaks to be misinterpreted and was solved by explicitly writing the file using UTF8. See [How to read and write UTF-8 to disk on the Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735323/how-to-read-and-write-utf-8-to-disk-on-the-android) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735323/how-to-read-and-write-utf-8-to-disk-on-the-android)