# How to read and write UTF-8 to disk on the Android?

Tags: java, android, utf-8, character-encoding

I cannot read and write extended characters (French accented characters, for example) to a text file using the standard InputStreamReader methods shown in the Android API examples. When I read back the file using:

```
InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
String str;
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
...
```

the string read is truncated at the extended characters instead of at the end-of-line. The second half of the string then comes on the next line. I'm assuming that I need to persist my data as UTF-8 but I cannot find any examples of that, and I'm new to Java.

Can anyone provide me with an example or a link to relevant documentation?

Comment: This is actually a general Java question.

Comment: Is it general Java? If you use openFileOutput to write to the private data area on Android, there is no constructor with a charset option: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Very simple and straightforward. :)

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/utf8_file.txt";
String UTF8 = "utf8";
int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath), UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that work when saving to the private data area as well?

Comment: Sure. Nothing Android-specific here above `openFileOutput(..)`.

Comment: Yes. You can replace generic `new FileOutputStream(filePath)` with Android's `openFileOutput(..)`.

Answer (score 10):

When you instantiate the `InputStreamReader`, use the constructor that takes a character set.

```
InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
```

And do a similar thing with `OutputStreamWriter`

I like to have a

```
public static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

in some utility class in my code, so that I can call (see more in the [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html))

```
InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in, MyUtils.UTF8);
```

and not have to handle `UnsupportedEncodingException` every single time.

Answer (score 1):

this should just work on Android, even without explicitly specifying UTF-8, because the default charset *is* UTF-8. if you can reproduce this problem, please raise a bug with a reproduceable test case here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry

Comment: I definitely had to change to UTF-8 to fix the bug. I had a postive result with my users who previously found that 'extended characters', such as French E circumflex, caused the file not to reread properly. I got a user to send me his file and when I read it back in the debugger I saw that the extended characters were being treated as a line-ending. I still have the original files. When I am back at home I will run up a test project using them to demonstrate. See my first question for code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700983/problem-saving-file-on-motorola-droid-android-2-1

Answer (score 0):

if you face any such kind of problem try doing this. You have to `Encode` and `Decode` your data into `Base64`. This worked for me. I can share the code if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of your file by right clicking it in the Project Explorer and selecting properties. If it's not the right encoding you'll need to re-enter your special characters after you change it, or at least that was my experience.