# How to read UTF-8 .txt file in android

Tags: android, file, utf-8

After searching at different resources I came up with following code

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(currentFileName), "UTF-8"));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        Log.d("line == " + line, "@@@@@@@@");
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("File not found", e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("IO Error", e.getMessage());
}
```

but it still doesn't do the job. I get ?????? at output.
any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it's the reading that's a problem rather than the logging? Have you tried logging the UTF-16 code units as hex?

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2735323/2982225)

Comment: what mean logging the UTF-16 code units as hex? i tried to put text into textview and it still "??????"